# Why the word "both" is considered as a determiner?

Tags: grammar

Why the word "both" is considered as a determiner (According to the Cambridge and the Collins dictionary)?
Example sentence: **Both kids walked a minute ago.**

Isn't it a quantifier? Also if yes then could you please tell me how to know when a word acts like a quantifier and when it acts like a determiner?

Comment: Yes, but 'quantifier' is not a word category (part of speech) like 'determiner' -- it's just a subclass of the determiner category. Other subclasses of determiner include degree, sufficiency, paucal, existential, cardinal numbers, demonstratives, articles and a few others. "Both" can be a determiner in, e.g. "Both copies were destroyed" or a predeterminer (modifier) in e.g. "He ate both those burgers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quantifiers](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quantifier) **are** determiners (though not all determiners are quantifiers).

There are many different types of determiner.  One way of classifying them is by [position](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/determin/ordering.htm): there are predeterminers ("twice", "double", "half", "all", "both"); central determiners ("the", "a", "this", "my", "your"); and postdeterminers ("one", "two", "three", "several", "many", "few").

Most quantifiers are *post*determiners, i.e. they come *after* an article or possessive adjective (where present): "the many people", "his few friends".

"All" and "both" are *pre*determiners, i.e. they come *before* an article or possessive adjective (where present): "all the boys", "both his sisters".